# withTrashed on the intermediate model of a hasManyThrough relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have 3 classes related like this:

```
Exhibitor
'- Bills
   '- Tickets
```

Bills and Tickets both use the SoftDeletes trait and on the Exhibitor class I have this relation:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Ticket::class, Bill::class);
}
```

I need to fetch all Tickets including the deleted ones (`withTrashed`), but this also needs to include all deleted Bills. Problem is, the withTrashed is only applied to the Tickets model, and not to the Bills.

This query

```
    $tickets = exhibitor()->tickets()->withTrashed()
        ->where('bills.updated_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($since))
        ->orderBy('tickets.id')
        ->get();
```

Generates this SQL

```
select `tickets`.*, `bills`.`exhibitor_id` from `tickets`
inner join `bills` on `bills`.`id` = `tickets`.`bill_id`
where `bills`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `bills`.`exhibitor_id` = ?
and `bills`.`updated_at` >= ?
order by `tickets`.`id` asc
```

Whereas i should need this SQL without the "`bills`.`deleted_at` is null" like this:

```
select `tickets`.*, `bills`.`exhibitor_id` from `tickets`
inner join `bills` on `bills`.`id` = `tickets`.`bill_id`
where `bills`.`exhibitor_id` = ?
and `bills`.`updated_at` >= ?
order by `tickets`.`id` asc
```

But i don't see any options where i can set the withTrashed() for the Bill model. I thought it should be possible to set a callback query on the hasManyThrough method, but according to the API there is no support for this. This seems so simple and i have the feeling i'm overlooking something, but i can't find it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23039

If you don't mind installing an external package, you can use this package I've created:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```php
class Exhibitor extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Ticket::class, [Bill::class])
            ->withTrashed('bills.deleted_at');
    }
}
```

Comment: This package is actually perfect. It also solves another issue i was having where i needed a 3-level nested relation. Thank you Jonas. I ended up creating a second relation on the Exhibitor class:

    public function ticketsWithTrashed()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Ticket::class, [Bill::class])->withTrashed(['bills.deleted_at'])->withTrashed();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would define a scope on the tickets model since the query is getting a bit complicated.

```php
public function scopeBillsSince($query, $since)
    return $query->whereHas('bills', function ($query2) use ($since) {
        return $query2->withThrashed()->where('updated_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($since))
    });
}
```

Using that scope now you can query tickets like this:

```php
$tickets = exhibitor()->tickets()->withTrashed()->billsSince($since);
```

Comment: As far as i know a scope query builds further upon `exhibitor()->tickets()->withTrashed()` and that is already missing the deleted bills, so I'm not sure how this can help, but i'll give it a try just to find out.

Comment: Just confirmed my suspicion, you can't modify the query already defined before the scope.